# How to add white-space / padding / margin around the outside of a finished page layout in InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign, page-layout, print-production, margin

I am recently working on an InDesign template, however when I export the template as PDF the contents of the page reach to the far left of the page. I want to leave some gap on the left side, center the content, whichever be best for printing and spiral binding.

- How can this be done without individually moving all elements?
- How can I add space around the outside of a finished page design, for use in home printing?

In the following image, the green borderline shows where I want my contents to be. I want it to be similar to the layout InDesign produces when it adds printer marks sans the marks.

> [image]

Comment: Hi there and welcome to GD! Not sure if I understand your problem. Could you add some screenshots of the problem? For example one that shows what you are doing in Indesign, and one shot of the resulting pdf?

Answer (score 1):

If you are planning on re-using or updating this regularly, the answer is that you have to move all the elements or rebuild the page.

You can grab everything, reduce it to 95%, and tweak to make it work, or re-create your document with the proper margins.

If you're going to print it once and never again, you could cheat by reducing just your printout to 95%, although it's a little sloppy and may not look right.

Answer (score 0):

No you must moving the elements, maybe with group all together moving is quick enough … other solution may be: create a new document with a empty box place it where u want it to have the space left, load the Indesign or Pdf file/pages and make the Pdf for printing.